# jQuery cycle stop on start and than play

Tags: jquery, cycle

there is a way to stop jQuery Cycle plugin on init and than start it from another function later in my code?

```
$('#cycle').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
           // stop it
        });

// than play it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#anotherElement').click(function(){
     $('#cycle').cycle({ fx: 'fade', // stop it });
});
```

Comment: I presumed he wanted it not to run on doc.ready but from another trigger?

Comment: Yes, i would like to know how to stop Cycle and than start Cycle when i need it

Comment: Well i hope the above helps :)

Comment: If you could be a bit more specific on what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
$('#s1').cycle({timeout:2000});

$('#pauseButton').click(function() { 
    $('#s1').cycle('pause'); 
});

$('#resumeButton').click(function() { 
    $('#s1').cycle('resume'); 
});
```